# lightning component in list view button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, list-view

How to use a lightning component in list view button for a contact object.

I want to perform some action on bulk using my lightning component.

I can't see any option.

I don't want to use visualforce page. By using visualforce page i can embed my lightning component into that.

Is their any other option to use lightning component directly on list view button.

Any suggestion??

Comment: As of Spring 17, the only way to do this is a visualforce page that embeds the lightning component. This is on the roadmap for a future release, but as always, do not make purchasing decisions based on forward looking statements!

Comment: is it possible to add action in list view button for lightning experience?

Comment: We want this too! Way more neat than having a proxy VF page.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way to directly call a lightning component from a list view button.  My advice would be to build it using lightning out in a visualforce page.  This will not only allow you to build it in lightning but it will also make it easy to transition it if and when they make it possible to link to lightning components from a list view button

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring 17, it is possible for Lightning Communities by creating a Lightning Component having a button in there.Then, just drag the Custom Button on the Object List View under the pages dropdown of Community Builder.
For Salesforce Lightning Page, you can create a Global Action and put your lightning component and then edit the Page layout of that Object and place that action on the detail page view of that object.