# list view javascript buttons in lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

I am working on creating equivalent lightning actions for the classic Javascript buttons as they are not available in lightning. Currently I am not able to find a clear way to create list view Javascript buttons from our classic into list view buttons which invoke a lightning component as the list view buttons can only call VF/URL/JS code. Only actions can be associated with lightning components and the actions cannot be associated with list views as far as I know.One option I could think of is to convert them into list view buttons with VF as their source. I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this in Lightning.

Comment: did you try Global Actions? If that does not work for you then this would be the duplicate question I believe - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154033/lightning-component-in-list-view-button

Comment: I have not tried using them for this specific scenario but in general global actions display on all the screens across different objects and these list view buttons are like specific to each object. One other thing is that I am not sure how to get the context of the selected records in the list view when multi select is allowed on that list view button.

Comment: Ahh, then I do not think it is possible yet without a VF page in play to use lightning out.